# Is there an appeal process for review queue access suspension?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I have been an active member of Stack Overflow (+1k rep). Recently I made a mistake in reviewing what I thought was a question, but ended up being a question asked in an answer.

[image]

Did I miss that it was marked an answer in the upper left of the page? Yes, yes I did, but those that actively edit and review first posts and answers know it can be easy enough to miss when you're engaged in reading the post.

My access to the review queues was suspended for five days. This appears to be a manual suspension as I did not fail an audit.

Is there a way to appeal this negative demerit? I hardly agree that a suspension is warranted in a simple mistake such as this.

Comment: Unless it's a manual ban, you won't be banned for just one mistake. That's just not how review queues works. For you to be banned there has to be a certain number of audits. Or, for you to do one 'bad enough' review for a Mod to ban you straight.  For fun... Which queue was it?

Comment: stackoverflow - first posts

Comment: And btw, review audits are meant to make sure people pay attention. 'it can easily be missed' means the system is working. You may need to pay more attention to the details in the stuff you review (again, depending if this is the first miss and a manual ban, or a repeat and automated)

Comment: Was it an audit? Like when you chose the wrong thing, did it automatically tell you you made a mistake?

Comment: No. I was editing and came back to the site and found that my access to the queue had been removed. Looking closer it said I edited an question that had been placed in the "answer" section. Like I said, acknowledge the mistake, but don't agree with the punishment :)

Comment: Automatic suspensions are definitely warranted when you've shown that you're regularly not paying attention. Such suspensions are only handed out automatically after multiple audit failures in a given period of time. If it was a manual suspension, then further clarification would be required from the moderator issuing the manual suspension, but usually there will be a moderator message detailing the reasoning behind the suspension.

Comment: But static, it's important to know what it is. If it's the automated ban, then it's different as it's a pattern of mistakes. Even if you ack the mistake, if it wasn't the first and a repeat pattern? It's still a problem. If you never really failed an audit and this is the first first time .. MAYBE it's more debatable? It really depends on the actual post and what has been done I guess, now that we know it was indeed a manual ban

Comment: It was a manual ban. I did not fail an audit

Comment: If it was a manual ban then there should be some kind of messaging detailing the reasoning behind the ban. If it was for one bad review, that wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: You recently reviewed this answer in the "First Posts" queue. Although posted as an answer, it did not attempt to provide an answer to the question that was asked. You should have flagged it as "not an answer" so that it could be removed. -- like a said, acknowledge a failure on my part, but don't feel it warrants a 5 day suspension especially considering my repoire

Comment: That.... Is indeed a manual ban for one mistake? IMHO (for what my opinion is worth...), It's a bit harsh indeed. Was the 'question' obviously an offtopic or awful question? It's definitely not a great review... But a ban for only this is definitely... Something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22283633

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the answer has been deleted :/ I can't see it.

Comment: VLQ only contains _answers_. If you stumble on a question, it's very likely to be a question in the "answer" box. Sometimes a real "question" pops up, then it's an audit.

Comment: By the time you reviewed this, the answer also already had a comment explaining what's wrong in decent detail. It would appear you ignored this piece of context, too.

Answer (score 58):

> Did I miss that is was marked an answer in the upper left of the page? Yes, yes I did…

Yes, yes you did ([10k+ only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710908/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-charts/54833285#54833285)).

> …but those that actively edit and review first posts and answers know it can be easy enough to miss when you're engaged in reading the post.

What? So, you're saying that when you are *actively* reviewing and thoroughly *engaged* in the process, it is easy to miss the fundamental nature of what you're reviewing? I mean, if so…this seems like a serious impediment to your ability to make accurate and helpful reviews.

> My access to the review queues was suspended for five days. This appears to be a manual suspension as I did not fail an audit.

Yes, indeed. This was a manual suspension by a diamond moderator. Specifically, me.

When I delete *really obvious* non-answers in response to "not an answer" flags, I like to play a little game. What I do is, I check to see who else, if anyone, reviewed that answer in one of the review queues, and what their decisions were. If I find someone who made the wrong decision, I will hand out a little suspension.

In most cases, I see these as serving more of an educational role than a punitive one. It's a way for a moderator to get a reviewer's attention and provide specific guidance on how they can improve. (Too many reviewers, for example, seem to be unaware of "not an answer" flags.)

I follow roughly the same algorithm here as do the automated suspensions. First-time "offenses" get very short suspensions (2–3 days is the standard period). For reviewers who have a *long history* of bad reviews, *or* those who have *recently* been suspended (either manually by a moderator or automatically by the system), I increase the suspension period, following a sliding scale.

Your history indicated that you had received an automated suspension from reviewing back in mid-January for failing an audit. As that was your first suspension, it was only for 2 days. For the second suspension, which I levied today, I determined that it was close enough in time to the first suspension that the time period should be compounded, and I therefore increased the suspension period to 5 days. (This was somewhat relaxed compared to the standard "second offense" period of 7 days.)

> Is there a way to appeal this negative demerit?

Yes, on Meta. This is the raison d'être of the [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension) tag. (For automated bans due to audits, use the [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) tag.) Ask a question, providing a link to the reviewed post, a copy of its contents, any necessary context, and a vigorous defense.

(Pro tip: "I clicked the wrong button" is a rather weak defense, but sometimes you get points for honesty.)

> I hardly agree that a suspension is warranted in a simple mistake such as this.

Well, again, I don't see this as a "simple" mistake. Failing to notice that an obvious non-answer was posted in the answer box, and failing to flag it accordingly, is literally defeating the entire purpose of the review queues and decreasing the quality of the site. What you're calling "simple", I'm seeing more as, "should have been obvious".

At the same time, as stated above, I see these types of suspensions (anything less than 30 days) as serving a primarily pedagogical purpose, as opposed to a punitive one. The goal is to *make you a better reviewer*, not to force you to stop reviewing. Since you clearly understand that your review was incorrect, and I trust that you will pay more attention in the future, I have lifted your review suspension.

Comment: Are arbitrary suspensions like this common practise? (Arbitrary in a site-wide sense -- even if you yourself have a system, it's just a matter of who gets there first). If it's a good idea should it not be codified/in the FAQ? The affected user was clearly confused what happened, which precludes any "learning" effect.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with your decision and reasoning.

Comment: @mfitzp I'm not sure how to answer "common practice". I always do it, and some of the other moderators do it on occasion, but they don't *all* do it. Nothing is codified in the FAQ regarding manual review suspensions. I don't think "confused" is a good objection to this. Note that there is a message presented to the user when they are suspended, written by the moderator who imposed the suspension. It clarifies what they did wrong, links to the incorrect review (or more than one, although there is a length limit on the message), and explains why they were banned. So...not really confusing.

Comment: It wasn't an objection to doing it (it seems fair) more a question of it being done more consistently to avoid confusion... but if there is an explanation perhaps that's enough. I've never been naughty enough to know how it works :)

Answer (score 15):

#### Is it an Automated or Manual Review Ban?

If it was an automated review ban, the duration will definitely be an **even number**, and the **review ban message** found on [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) will begin with *"You have made too many incorrect reviews"*.

In this case, a moderator wanted to highlight your action(s) on specific review(s) to you.

---

#### Review Suspension Appeals

If you want to discuss the review or appeal the ban, then feel free to [ask a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=review-suspension+discussion) on Meta with the tag [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension).

In the question, you should include:

- the suspension message (including links to the reviews)
- screenshots of the review if the post is currently deleted (for <10k rep users)
- an explanation of why you think the suspension is incorrect and/or should be lifted

Comment: Should I ask something more specific than I already have? Or I guess, should I not add that tag to this post?

Comment: I've already answered your original question, so you'll have to ask a new question described above. You should include the suspension message, screenshots of the review if the post is currently deleted (for <10k users), and explain why you think the suspension is excessive or incorrect (in the question itself)

Comment: `[faq-proposed]`? Or does it already exist? Don’t remember seeing it spelled out so clearly.