# You have made too many incorrect reviews. 4 day ban

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I'm attempting to find the question which resulted in this ban, however, when I'm attempting to look it I'm unable to:

[image]

The above is the latest review I performed that I can see, which appears all right. But when trying to find the cause of my ban I'm unable to.

Are these found in a different location?

Comment: The post may have been deleted.

Comment: @JeanneDark if that's the case is there no option to simply view the judgment?

Comment: @Matthew There's generally a link to the bad reviews (or at least one of them) provided in the review ban message, did you miss it or was there no review link/ID provided?

Comment: The specific review audit you failed that pushed you over the edge can only be seen by a moderator. They can provide you with more details if/when they see this question. Regular users can take a look at your public review records in general and tell you if any pattern needs addressing in the future, if you want.

Comment: @NickA it's completely possible I've missed it at my own fault, I believe it was due to saying it's okay to an answer which pointed to a link (albeit, I believe did answer but understand why I had the ban applied) I just wondered if it was possible to review it.

Comment: you probably misused Requires Editing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24132724), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24133023), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24132818), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24131123). See guidance on how to triage [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/839601)

Comment: @yivi thanks for the feedback, if a moderate could I would find it extremely beneficial. I do understand, after reading into it, why the ban is in place (I shouldn't accept link answers, even if the link does indeed contain the answer) I just wanted to see if I could view it

Comment: @gnat It's possible I have but in the first comment, it leaned towards two edits and one unsalvageable. Point 2 also had 3 vs 2 and believe the need for edit remains, point 3 also 3 edits + 1 unsalvagable and the last one being again the majority agreeing with myself. I will, however, read through the provided link, thanks

Comment: Wow, the four reviews @gnat has posted are pretty bad. Almost every one chose the wrong option on those. So being with the majority doesn't help when the majority is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is accessible when you are review banned, but usually you can view your Triage review history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history). That should include the ones on deleted posts. (Or in case your last review wasn't on Triage, you can see the history of First posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) and of Late answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history).)

Comment: @Matthew For your reference, it was: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24133330

Comment: @JonClements thank you

Comment: @Tom thanks for pointing that out, I think I'm maybe not so good at noticing - can you let me know what I did wrong in each of those so I know going forward?

Comment: Gnat already linked you a guideline on how to review items on the Triage queue. Please read it and then re-check the linked review questions. You can't change your vote, but you check if you would vote differently after reading the guide.

Comment: In this case the audits weren't from Triage, and it is an automated review suspension. Also, moderators have an advanced tool page that we can use to monitor review audits, audit failures, and review stats for each queue. CC: @gnat

Comment: @SamuelLiew  anyway, I think you better check first three examples in [my prior comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389731/you-have-made-too-many-incorrect-reviews-4-day-ban#comment729772_389731) and teach mistaken reviewers (fourth example is more of gray area and I doubt that it warrants mod intervention)

Comment: @gnat oh yes of course, but I'm doing it from the H&I https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389149 and I have a userscript to close H&I questions and linking to the related triage, and a userscript for assisting in review bans status/duration + pro-forma messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the four failed audits within the past 14 days, that gave you the **automated** ban:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24133330
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24069787
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24051748
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24051798

As the previous review ban duration was 2 days (whether you saw it or not), and it is recent (ending less than 30 days ago), the duration this time has doubled to 4.

---

To see whether you are currently review banned, as well as the reason for the review suspension, simply visit https://stackoverflow.com/review

To find out whether the review suspension is a result of failing review audits (automated), or manually applied by a moderator, see my answer on [Is there an appeal process for review queue access suspension?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380509/584192)

Comment: I didn't expect the attention this thread has received but thankful for all the replies, thanks again

Comment: No problem, if you have any questions about the review and audit system please just ask!

Comment: is it possible to get information on how long these stay on my account (incorrect choices) ?

Comment: Forever, because you can't change your completed reviews. IIRC 4 audit failures within a 14-day period triggers an automated suspension. If last review ban ended < 30 days ago, duration is doubled. Otherwise duration is halved. IIRC technically you could possibly get another review ban by failing one more audit within the next ~20 days.

Comment: Thanks, going forward I'll just use skip a lot more than I have been doing :)