# Incorrectly failed review audit (I believe), review banned

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I recently failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24351667), over an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary/58240291#58240291), which placed me in an automated review ban. I say it's automated based off [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380509/11384392).

I disagree with the audit. The system notified me that it had identified the post as possible spam, so before providing feedback I looked at the question's other answers to check for potential plagiarism sources. Seeing no direct copies, I spun up the [handy-dandy MetaSmoke search](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search) to see if there had been any reports for that post or user. Once again, nothing. The user under review had numerous other, legitimate answers; I figured it was a safe bet that this answer was alright as well.

Having satisfied myself that the post wasn't spam, I gave it a last look-over. The answer used methods similar to those found other answers, but different enough that (I thought) it could stand on its own. So I clicked the "No Action Needed" button.

Apparently that was the wrong choice, and I got slapped into the timeout box. Normally I'd use that as an excuse to take the weekend off, but this timeout situation has happened before via a similar process (system-marked possible spam, didn't see anything to back that up, then "wrongly" marked as ok). For both this case as well as the previous one, I was only given one post in the ban message as an example of tasks I should have reviewed differently. From that I can only assume both timeouts were dispensed as a direct result of those individual failures, rather than a series of failures directly preceding them.

If I was indeed wrong, I would appreciate some guidance as to what I should have done additionally/differently. As far as I know, I performed my due diligence for that review and I don't believe I should be in timeout.

Comment: Good that you've done your research prior voting, so you were paying attention. But you missed one thing: that's a pretty thin answer with no real value on a pretty old question with many other, better answers. There's no reason to keep that around.

Comment: @Tom I tend to be relatively lenient in that regard, usually commenting on the answer asking them to edit; rarely do I give out downvotes or flags unless it's super bad. I guess I must have been distracted by the "possible spam" warning and focused too much on that possibility. I may need to tighten my standards for what should be considered "worth keeping". I agree with you in that I should have at least commented on their post, but I don't think I should have been insta-banned for that failure.

Comment: Well, you still can be lenient if you want, but you would then need to skip such review items. And you're not insta-banned for that failure, but for a sum of failures (for example X failed audits in a certain period of time). So thus audit was just the last one that pushed you over the threshold. And in the end it is not that bad. There still much you can do and you've learned a few more things about reviewing, so that's a good thing, right?

Comment: Ah, it was my understanding that if you got banned for multiple failures over a short time, that all those recent failures would be shown in the ban message displayed on the review page. Seeing only one on that page, I had concluded that the linked post was the only factor.
I do skip reviews, frequently. I think if you're not *extremely sure* about another choice, that's what should be chosen.

Comment: Yes, it was an automatic ban, not imposed manually by a moderator. I...have no idea why the system thought that answer was spam. It was never flagged as spam by anyone. It was deleted by 4 community users through the review queues in response to a VLQ flag. No moderator ever touched that one.

Comment: @CodyGray Me neither. What's weirder is that this is the second time this has happened to me, though I don't have the link to the post that "got me"
 last time.

Comment: I do: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24195160). That one [was deleted by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23947643), you then got the audit (which you failed, because you disagreed with the community's decision to delete it), and then the next day, [a moderator undeleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57758659/timeline).

Comment: :/ Go figure. Looking back though, I probably deserved that one. It's an on-the-fence thing. Should have skipped it.

Comment: @CodyGray I assume there's no course of recompense for this? If I need to sit down and take my lumps I will, but it's kinda unfortunate that these weird cases should get me in the doghouse like this.

Comment: Uh, there is. A moderator can unban you. I've been known to do this, but before I will unban someone who has been given an automatic ban, I have to go through their review history and make sure that they don't actually deserve the ban. The system is designed such that you are never banned for a single failed audit: there's always a history of "incorrect" reviews that contributes to the ban. The ban message just selects a single one of them (I think the latest one) to highlight as an example. I haven't had a chance to go through your review history and make that call...

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Didn't mean to try to rush anything. Just curious

Comment: I don't think you should be lenient on late answers that add nothing.  For the high rep users who still care about curating the good Q&As, those answers are pestiferous.  And hard work to get rid of.  Besides, we >>do<< need to teach new users to direct their enthusiasm in constructive directions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second part of the answer is incorrect. `max(stats.keys())` will not give you the argmax of the dictionary values.

It is not spam, but it isn't correct either.  You should downvote it.

If you don't know enough python to judge it, then you should skip.

I'm also no fan of the audit review messages.  While we're on the subject of kindness, dignity and codes of conduct, I'd love to see some CoC guidelines requiring bots to address volunteers politely, e.g. "I'm sorry, but that's not the review we were hoping for" instead of the domineering imperative of "Stop, Look and Listen!"

While it is true our robot overlords are on their way, and human re-education will surely be one of their tasks, I expected that to begin maybe in a regimented, dehumanized environment like prison or a military unit, not with volunteers at a Q&A site that wants to improve UX.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Yeah, OP didn't want the max of the keys lol. I should have seen that myself. I'll shut up and take my lumps now.

Comment: Being incorrect isn't a reason to close a post though. Downvote, sure, but I agree that no action is *needed*