# Appealing 4 day Review ban for 'Requires Editing' (https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24391499)

Tags: support, status-completed, disputed-review-audits, triage, review-suspension

I'm appealing a 4 day review ban based on an answer in Meta which says I can do this.

The basis of my appeal is that the ban I've been given does not appear to comply with the protocols (as I understand them).  If I have indeed misunderstood then I respectfully ask that my 'appeal' simply to be someone put me straight, so that I don't 'go wrong' again.

A previous Meta question sets out the requirements for an appeal, and I will follow these guidelines ([Is there an appeal process for review queue access suspension?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380508/is-there-an-appeal-process-for-review-queue-access-suspension/380509#380509)) 
Hereafter, for clarity, I will refer to the above link as the '*guidelines*'

" ...ask a new question on Meta with the tag review-suspension.
In the question, you should include:

- the suspension message (including links to the reviews)
- screenshots of the review if the post is currently deleted
- an explanation of why you think the suspension is incorrect and/or
  should be lifted "

**Suspension Message**
Your review on triage/24391499 wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148.

Come back in 4 days to continue reviewing.

**Link to Review**
The guidelines state use a screenshot if the post has been deleted. The link to the Review is still extant: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24391499
**:

[Screenshot added for clarity as original question deleted by post owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peTpF.png)

**Explanation for Appeal**

- Although my ban is for four days (even number) I don't believe it was automated because the response does not begin with the words mentioned in the *guidelines* "You have made too many incorrect reviews".
- Elsewhere on the linked Meta question there's a comment that it doesn't matter if previous reviewers have concurred with my 'Requires Editing' decision, because they might all be wrong. Nevertheless I do believe that the other reviewers who concurred are a part of my evidence for appeal
- On the post in question, prior to me marking 'Requires Editing'. I have commented to the post owner "Please can you add a minimal reproducible example of your code". Therefore I submit that I did try to make a 'helpful' addition to the post, I was paying attention and being careful
- I genuinely believed (erroneously) that 'Requires Editing' was the pertinent response to make on this review
- I respectfully submit that the clarification on the ban "*If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead.*" should have been available to me before I clicked 'Requires Editing'. If the information is only available afterwards then I'm prepared to learn from it of course, but accompanied with a 4 day ban seems unjust.

I think this appeal post is long enough without any further text.

I would like the ban lifted or modified if that is possible. But, if not, then if someone could make a clarification in the comments I'd really appreciate it, so that, as I've already stated, I don't make the same mistake again.

Thanks for taking the time to read my appeal and for your consideration of this matter : )

Comment: If you can answer this correctly I'll lift the review ban immediately: **In Triage, when you select "Requires Editing", *who* should be the one editing the post to improve it?**

Comment: Have you read the linked post in the message? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me _ My answer is that it should be reviewers or other SO contributors _ NOT the post owner (I understand this was my error)

Comment: Do you know why selecting "requires editing" here for other users to edit this question is incorrect?

Comment: I did read the post you have linked to and some of the comments but not all _ and yes I have now understood (with the delayed explanation) my decision was incorrect _ I connected my comment on the post for a minimal reproducible example to the Requires Editing button _ This was wrong and I understand that now

Comment: in answer to "Do you know why selecting "requires editing" here for other users to edit this question is incorrect?" - Other users couldn't edit the question because they didn't have access to the poster's code or other data

Comment: Thanks, I've lifted the review ban. Do keep this in mind and avoid selecting "requires editing" unnecessarily as it creates more work for everyone.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use comments to say 'thanks' _ but I do genuinely appreciate being given a second chance _

Comment: As a sidenote, could you please not use underscore instead of other punctuation? It makes the text hard to read.

Comment: _"The guidelines state use a screenshot "_, yep people <10k rep may not be able to see deleted thing. That's why. If a 10K or the autor may edit a picture it will be cool.

Comment: Off topics comment: But Thank you! For comming here with no rant. With a really civil ton. I 've favorited this  question so I can come back every time I get burn on a meta rant.