# Too many incorrect reviews, banned for 1.5 years

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

I admit, I'm what you call a rep whore :-)

As I'm currently without a job, I thought it might be useful spending some time on this site, e.g. by doing some review tasks.

Although I try to do this in a serious way, I've fallen into three "Stop and Listen" traps (as I didn't understand the second one, I'd added a comment). In top of that, I'm back after a ban for half a year.

Now I seem to be banned from the review for 1.5 year, after what seems like just three wrong reviews.

Guys, aren't you being far too severe here?

Comment: You were banned for half a year. That half-year ban was intended to make you reflect and think why you got banned in the first place. Since then, you fail three audits. If you were an automated system: looking into the reviewing data you have.... is reviewing something the system should encourage to you? Considering whatever mistake is done requires the work of multiple people to fix?

Comment: No, this is what the progressive review ban system was designed for. You don't need /review to participate. Flag and vote on posts in the tags you frequent is also needed.

Comment: _" I'm what you call a rep whore"_ I didn't think reviewing gave any rep?

Comment: Reviewing does *not* give any rep, @dustytrash. You do get badges, after reaching certain milestones, but that doesn't translate into reputation. The review queues are intentionally not gamified, in order to avoid people breaking things in a misguided attempt to earn reputation.

Comment: What I find most tragically impressive is that you managed to dig a 512 day hole before realizing something was wrong and asking for help.  Normally these questions show up around the 1 month auto-ban point; when it's still possible for a bit of user education in how to review correctly to turn things around.

Comment: Why? Review is not about getting rep. Review is about cleanning the site.   
What the point of having a quality-checker that does not clean nor check?  
Yes it is a tedious work, but it's an important one. 
That's the exact reason review and rep gain are not related. 
It's too important, to let bad reviewer into the review queue.

Comment: I will still recommend reading [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).

Answer (score 36):

It takes real discipline to get yourself into this position. Whether it is through sustained apathy or recklessness, I don't know, and I won't even attempt to wager a guess.

Moderators do sometimes impose manual bans on reviewers who consistently make incorrect decisions in the review queues, but the maximum length of time that we can ban someone in this way is 1 year (365 days).

You, however, have been banned for 512 days. That can only happen via [the automatic system, which doubles the length of the review ban each time you fail audits in close succession](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system/256234#256234). This is evident from your review history ("Comment" is the explanatory message you would have been shown during each ban):

[image: User's review history, showing all automatically-imposed bans and the dates. Started with a 2-day ban on November 6, 2017, culminating in the current 512-day ban on January 14, 2020, with the length of ban roughly doubling each time.]

That is the automatic system working as designed, to catch bad reviewers. The hope is that they'll learn and improve. But even if not, at least they are stopped.

Let me say this again, just to be clear: feel free to take this as a signal that we do not want you using the review queues anymore. At this point, you are just doing more harm than good. Audits don't catch everything. All the incorrect reviews you've made in-between have just fallen through the cracks, potentially leaving poor-quality content up on the site. You've either entirely missed the point of reviewing, or you just don't care. Either way, find some other way to contribute to Stack Overflow, or don't contribute at all.

Comment: *Moderators do sometimes (rarely) impose manual bans on reviewers* This year, [more than 40% of total review bans were imposed manually by mods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392573).

Comment: Heh. [I impose a lot of manual review bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380508/is-there-an-appeal-process-for-review-queue-access-suspension/380522#380522). Most of them are quite short in duration, though.

Comment: Impressive, wow. I wonder if [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) is applicable.

Comment: @Monkey Yes, perhaps. I deliberately tried to write the answer so as not to guess about the motives of the reviewer or the cause of all this, but simply to focus on the facts: demonstrably poor reviewing makes the site worse, rather than better, so regardless of the reason, it's time to stop.

Comment: I just don't agree to this sentence: *At this point, you are just doing more harm than good*. Maybe, but maybe not. Current system is just an audit error counter. Theoretically, after the last ban period doubling, he could have done 20 correct reviews for 5 queues for 29 days (before 30 days ban period having). 2900 reviews, with 80-100 passed audits, and he/she (they? :)) would have banned anyway at the first audit mistake. This is not likely the case, but I strongly believe that the passed audit ratio (as high as you want. 90%? 95%? Ok!) would be a far fairer metric.

Comment: @Cubo Yes, if a reviewer somehow managed to identify audits and intentionally fail them, while was making correct (or mostly correct) decisions in other cases, it is theoretically possible that the statement "you are just doing more harm than good" would not apply to them. Although this is within the realm of theoretical possibility, it is...not likely. I can, of course, go through a user's full review history and see all the decisions they made, not just audits, and judge what I believe their "success" rate is. However, I am currently lacking any inducement to do that in this case.

Comment: @CodyGray since (I hope for you) you are not going to browse all non-audit revision, all you can do is to base our statistics on audits (if not we are implicitely admitting that audits are not statistically representative of the reviews population, and then useless and/or misleading). So: why an user failing an audit after (let's say) 32 passed audits should be marked as _"more harmful than helpful_? In my example they are 3.3% harmful and 96.7% helpful. So why isn't fail ratio better than absolute fails?

Comment: Ps: an user could have _consumed_ their initial fails tolerance in the initial phase of their reviewer "career". After that they could have achieved a good ratio.

Comment: @CodyGray Sometimes the audits themselves are wrong, of course.

Comment: Sometimes they are, @user253751. They shouldn't be, but they sometimes are. I have some ideas on how to fix that, namely letting moderators nominate *obvious* posts to be audit candidates. In the meantime, we will just have to accept the fact that algorithmically-selected and generated audits are not going to be perfect. It's why we have the [[meta-tag:disputed-review-audit]] tag here on Meta. I do pay attention to those posts. And...again, not to be a broken record here, but... *thirteen audits are not wrong*.