# Is there Review Ban History feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-suspension

I was recently banned from the Review Queue due to failing to recognize something should have been closed instead of requires editing. Based on reading several meta articles, I understand now what “Requires Editing” means, that is indicates the questions could become answerable if someone from the community edited the content or style. I mistakenly thought it meant the question would remain open for the OP to improve it by providing more information that was lacking. I have the habit of leaving comments to that effect (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25299091) for the response that led to my ban).

Nevertheless, it took me quite a bit of effort to find out I was banned. I received no notification of any type other than the “There are no review queues available to you” message.

My request is that we could be able to view a history of all our reviews that lead to a ban, or that those particular reviews are flagged in some way within the “Review History”.

Perhaps this is already a feature and I have only one ban to my name thus far, however, I know now that I have made mistakes particularly as it involves “Requires Editing” and I want to be able to track my mistakes and improve my overall participation in the review process.

Comment: A history of all your reviews is here, linked from "activity -> reviews" in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6917743/wlh?tab=activity&sort=reviews. This includes audits. If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/review, it will show you the message explaining why you are banned (if you are currently banned). As a moderator, I can also see your reviews in different queues at: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?userId=6917743 (change "triage" in the URL to see reviews in other queues). I don't know if that works for you on your own account or not. It may be mod-only.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I have seen all those. And I can see the current message. I was speaking more about a history of such occurrences. This might also help people track any bans as each successive ban within a set time period increases the length of the ban.

Comment: Ah, I see: a specific history of your review bans.  That *does* exist, but I'm 99% certain it is moderator-only. For any user account, I can view a history of their review bans, including date, duration, levying party (moderator or automatic), and the message that was associated with the ban and shown to the user at the time. I have an answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392946) with a screenshot. Having that history available to moderators makes sense, but I think the idea behind not showing it to everyone is forgiveness. You aren't supposed to dwell on mistakes made in the past.

Comment: The amount of effort it took for you (and everyone else) to determine that they were banned from reviewing [is *definitely* a bug, and one that desperately needs to be fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned). I think if that were resolved, it would make what you're asking for here a lot less necessary.

Comment: Exactly my case, except that my ban has already expired and I can't find anymore why I have been banned. I may be in permanent *review strike*.

Comment: Had the same issue, luckly I manually check the `/review` url (no idea why). I feel [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving) should also be linked as it helped me understand why the ban is so severe. Now off to wait until the ban lifts I guess.