# Review Ban Appeal for triage/25566186

Tags: support, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

Yesterday, I was completing some Triage reviews and came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25566186) on [Use Ionicons instead of jpg in React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613937/use-ionicons-instead-of-jpg-in-react-native). I honestly paid attention to all reviews because I had come out of a previous ban (which also puzzled me).

I do not honestly see how this post is uneditable. There is a comment from a user with 2,000+ reputation who edited the post and an answer which proves it is understandable.

I personally read it and understood it.

Could the user add a bit more clarity? Yes, like many other posts — but it was understandable.

I came back this morning to enjoy my usual new routine of reviews and I get a message that am banned for 7 days.

It turns out that all 3 reviewers took same decision as I did.

My question/appeal:

1. Who takes the decision to ban us even if we took a good decision (I am assuming its automated)
2. How do I appeal against this? because I want to continue reviews (I love it). and if this is how to do it, then please consider this as my appeal against my ban.

Comment: Very relevant here: "[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/1364007)"

Comment: It's not automatic. A moderator review-suspended you manually, because you chose "requires editing" on a question that could only be fixed by the question author. That other users chose wrongly is not relevant.

Comment: What if I could edit the question to clarify it? would that take my ban off? Cos honestly I do understand how frustrating wrong reviews can be and I do not want to hold records of ban reviews or frustrating processes. That is why I really need this lifted.

Comment: Just to clarify: you reviewed the first version of that question and not the one after two edits.

Comment: @Tom yes! and after rightly reviewing it, Someone did edit it. before the OP as well edited it.

Comment: And the question still got closed after the user edit, so that isn't a strong argument for your case. You should first start appealing to the closing of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ban has been lifted.

So there is a chatroom found from this link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews. where you could discuss your ban and hopefully get the resolution needed.

I wouldnt exactly say I was wrongly banned. It's more like between a rock and a hard place situation and am glad it has been resolved.

Problems around the Triage seems to be long existing and is being solved daily.