# Unwanted triage result

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension

I have been review-suspended for a wrong [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25633402). I am not here to complain as I respect the decision, and would like to understand if I am doing wrong or what.

The facts are that I hit "Looks OK", however that wasn't what I did (or at least what I consciously did).

It already happened in the past (and I let it go). Usually, when I review from a mobile device I get banned.

My mobile device is an Android Q, 5.2" screen size, and I use Firefox in Desktop Mode.

The pattern that seems to cause this trouble is the following:

I hit "Unsalvageable", then scroll down to the dialog, then choose "The Question should be closed" and then, instead of clicking the reason, I hesitate and cancel the dialog to re-read the question since I wanted to be sure. Then, I repeat the process at least another time because I was thinking about to leaving a comment. Then repeated again, and finally voted for closing.

I noted that sometimes the outcome is "Looks Okay" or "Requires Editing" even though I voted for closing.

I searched the meta and nobody seems to have this problem. Am I misusing the triage site? (or better, is it supported reviewing from a mobile device?).

Comment: If these accidents happen to you often enough when reviewing on mobile, maybe you should not review on mobile. Mistaken reviews, for whatever the reason, are detrimental.

Comment: You are right. I won't be using it anylonger. I saw the triage queue overloaded and wanted to help.

Comment: Note that Triage is [considered by many to be a mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1). Some of the mods are working to fix it.