# Review Ban Appeal for triage/25678209

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

For the past couple of days I noticed that I had no review queues available to me. I just recently realized that this means I have been review banned. (I have seen the same message before and believe I've been review banned a couple times in the past)

I found out about stackoverflow.com/review and happened upon this message:

> Your review on triage/25678209 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead. If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue work?.
>
> Come back on Jul 30 at 8:40 to continue reviewing.

I now understand that I simply misunderstood the difference between "Requires Editing" and "Unsalvageable". My incorrect reviews were simply because of a misunderstanding and have nothing to do with ill-intend. I had no idea that I was banned or have been banned before and therefore had no clue that I was doing something wrong.

I am very sorry about the issues this may have caused and wonder if there is something I can do to maybe get my ban lifted or shortened as I promise you that it wasn't my intention to deliberately misjudge questions/answers. I genuinely am impressed with the ecosystem that is in place to keep StackOverflow running and hope that I can add to it again soon.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498)'s why you didn't know what Requires Editing means.

Comment: The same thing happened to me so welcome to the club. Moral: stay out of triage, it’s a death trap.

Comment: Yes i avoid reviewing too, because i can't comprehend the rules, sometimes so sometimes so, why do they ask a users opinion, if they don't follow it and the punish them for that opinion