# Hit the wrong button got a review ban

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

Can anyone let me know why one wrong click on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25766331) post lead to a review ban?

Why is the ban not clear when you go back into the review queue?

I eventually found this banner:

> Your review on triage/25766331 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing"
>   option should only be used when other community users (like you) are
>   able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better
>   shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified
>   by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead.
>   If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see
>   Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue
>   work?. Come back on Apr 21 at 1:48 to continue reviewing.

Why such a long ban? and the text above implies this should only impact the triage queue.
If one bad click out of over 900 is enough to get a ban then I don't see much point in wasting my time in future to try and help maintain the community...

Edit3: As indicated by [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) and makes perfect sense post coffee - if the ban wasn't long enough to notice then what would be the point! it may not be seen (Though a message would be more effective imho)

Was this an automated ban or a manual ban?

Edit:
I realise my mistake, and I've just been directed to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving) discussion which actually echo's my thoughts and the incorrect use of the 'Requires Editing' button.

A better button may be 'Requires Editing by OP' and to rename the current button to something better. I will have a read through that post fully later and see what I can contribute.

Edit2: As pointed out the VTC is actually an indicator to the OP that action is required, but... Does the OP still get a little number bubble next to the close text? if yes then that should really be improved to bring more attention (I've not seen it in a very long time so it may have changed since then)

Also wouldn't it be a good idea to send a user a message when a ban or similar action is taken and in this day and age of transparency detail who banned, was it manual or automated and with some accompanying notes if it was manual by a human.

Edit4:
And whilst [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) was so kind to point out my past failings it should be noted they where from years ago before I was more engaged and aware of how things worked...with time comes experience and learning.

Comment: The suspension is two week long so you have an opportunity to see it. If it were shorter, and you didn't attempt to review until the suspension lapsed, you would never see the the suspension message and would never be made aware of what you did wrong and what you could do better in the future. If you understand that "requires editing" was the wrong choice there, when a mod sees your post they may lift the review-suspension.

Comment: Where is the code that causes the problem? How can the question be answered without it? Bans are always across all queues to prevent you from continuing to cause havok elsewhere.

Comment: there wasn't hence i hit the wrong button it should have been unsaleable! and @yivi that makes sense then. Alas the 'requires editing' button is badly labelled and imho should be removed or renamed to something else.

Comment: See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/) (currently featured) to read about efforts to improve/fix Triage.

Comment: Ohh interesting.. and it shares some of my exact thoughts! I actually learnt a long time ago that 'requires editing' send its off to the H&I queue which is actually useless when most of the time people are appearing to click that link when they feel the post required editing by the OP to add details etc. In fact I'd made sure to keep away from the button. My trips to the H&I queue also showed the other side of the problem so that made me acutely aware what is wasn't for!

Comment: something like 'Requires Editing by OP' would be a useful button with a limit set so that if the OP doesn't update the post within a given time it dies.(or something)

Comment: "requires editing by OP" already exists. It's called "flag/vote to close". The only problem are the labels (or maybe Triage and H&I existence at all, but that's for another discussion).

Comment: That's true! Does the OP still just get the tiny number next to the close button at the bottom of the post or has that been improved to draw attention to the fact is been flagged for them to look at?

Comment: they where along time ago before I was more engaged and aware of how things worked...with time comes experience and learning.  @RobertLongson

Comment: More recent examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25772198) Looks OK but has typo in title, [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25771691) Looks OK but has wrong capitalization all over the place,

Comment: You very rarely pick requires editing (that's why I had to go back a long way) and that's certainly a point in your favour. I've removed my previous comment listing them as it's no longer needed. Given you've explained you understand when requires editing is appropriate that may be enough for a moderator to unban you.

Comment: @RobertLongson - thank you. Yes I realised a while back requires editing is not what it seems hence I stopped using it! and once I got access to the H&I I saw the problem first hand hence I think I've never done much other than skip - I may have edited a grand sum of 1 post.

Comment: Since this was the only "Requires Editing" action you did recently, I'll reset the duration and let you off this time.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thank you. Indeed I always try to learn from my mistakes and draw on what wisdom has been bestowed.

Comment: @user3788685 - It wasn't just one mistake.  You made multiple mistakes, and clicked the wrong button, on multiple reviews.

Comment: @SecurityHound everyone can be a critique - a teacher offers some guidance...

Answer (score 2):

> Why such a long ban?

[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1)

> Was this an automated ban or a manual ban?

Manual. If it's not about too many failed audits, it's usually manual.

> Does the OP still get a little number bubble next to the close text?

If they have 500 or more reputation, yes. Now, however, the OP finally gets a notification when their question is closed and an edit link to improve it, along with some guidance.

> Also wouldn't it be a good idea to send a user a message when a ban or similar action is taken and in this day and age of transparency detail who banned, was it manual or automated and with some accompanying notes if it was manual by a human.

Don't you see how this would be exploited? "It says a *HUMAN* banned me! That little ****, I'm going to downvote all his posts!"

Comment: That's a very good point - I forget that people can be petty and silly like that...