# Request to lift a review suspension for a new reviewer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

I made an incorrect tag of "Requires Editing" which led to a ban. I understand the need for this, as I had been using it incorrectly. I understand now that option should only be used if the user has already provided all the information required and other users can make the question more clear. I'm sure this wasn't the first time I had made this error, thus I'm ok that this ban happened to educate me. Mission accomplished, right?

The issue that I have is that the review was on 3/30, and I have been banned until 5/2! I would really like to continue contributing the the community, and feel this is far too harsh a ban for a first time offense (at least the first time I was notified). I would like to appeal to have my review privileges restored now, or at least earlier than 5/2.

Thank you for consideration. For reference, here is the ban comment.

*Your review on triage/25729855 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead. If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue work?.*

*Come back on May 2 at 2:40 to continue reviewing.*

Comment: 32 days, sounds like you already completed a 16 day ban, which didn't help apparently.

Comment: Well if I did, I never saw it. Up til now I had only been doing a few reviews every once in a while. So there could be another discussion on how it's possible I was banned but didn't know it (which obviously doesn't help either). But that aside, now that I know and am better educated, I'd like to further contribute to the community by helping with reviews. I think my question and answer record shows that I know how to write good questions, I just needed to be better educated on how to use the review tags.

Comment: The ban message shows excellent exanples for further reading: *For more information, see Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue work?*

Comment: And also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1 which has been featured in the sidebar for over a month now.

Comment: I made this post based on recommendations from the "Getting banned from Triage reviews" post. That post and a few others I linked to were the source of my education. My apologies for not seeing the sidebar article. This was literally my first time on stackoverflow META and I only made my way here from the link on the banned message.

Comment: My point still remains that a 32 day ban is excessive for someone who 1) never received notification or otherwise noticed he was banned, 2) now better understands the triage process, and 3) has a great track record on SO and wants to continue to contribute to the community. So to whoever has such power, I am still requesting an early lift to my ban.

Comment: The reason this suspension is longer is so you had the opportunity to actually see the message. As you clearly point out, the shorter suspension is easily missed if one is not a frequent reviewer; in which case it serves no purpose at all.

Comment: That’s all well and good. But the purpose of this post was to say I’ve seen it, I’ve learned, and request that the ban be lifted early. I’m not looking for a discussion on the ban procedure, just requesting the ban be lifted early.

Comment: @samuelliew I'm sure this comment will be met with negativity, but I just got hit by this again. I strongly disagree with the ban. It was a post where language was unclear, and the user had provided additional information in the comments. I would have edited it myself if I was able. That is the criteria I started applying to the use of that tag but still I got banned. I get the feeling we are not really supposed to use the Requires Editing tag except in extreme circumstances... Maybe the community really doesn't want me as a reviewer, but if so, a ban until June 20 is not going to help...

Comment: @samuelliew and FWIW even though that question ended up getting closed as needs more focus, it actually was answered and accepted (even without the edits). So clearly it wasn't in such bad shape. If I came across it myself I would have just edited it for clarity and integrated the comments into the question.