# What criteria are used to allow someone to respond to items in the review queues?

Tags: support, review-suspension

What criteria are used to control review queue availability? I was happily reviewing queues until about a week ago. Now I get a little red blob on the queues icon but when I click on it I get told that 
`There are no review queues available to you`.

Did I say/do something wrong? Or did I not say/do something right?

Comment: and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1

Comment: Your action of requires editing on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25743119) was incorrect and a moderator has banned you from reviewing as a result. If you edit this question to explain that you now understand that was the wrong thing to do and why you will likely get unbanned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742559, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742488, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25743119, etc.