# Closed questions are being used to teach reviewers in Triage to click "Requires Editing" when the outcome should be "Unsalvageable" (closed)!

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred, review-audits, triage

Example Triage audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25979021

> [image]

I've closed this question a month ago, but it is still being used as a poor Triage audit, requiring the reviewer to pick "Requires Editing", even while I [have been campaigning that this is not the correct option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/584192).

Can I request that the criteria the system uses to pick audits like these, also take into account the question status as well?

Otherwise I may have to take it further and review suspend users who pass such audits, and linking back to this Meta post.

---

**More examples:**

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25979021
https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25992338
https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25991263

Comment: yepp i fell sometimes short and unbelieving what option i should have taken instead of my choice. the hole system is as far as i read in renewal, i hope the users find more inconsistencies.

Comment: Updated to `status-planned` since we have some active research on this scheduled. More here soon!

Comment: similar: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)

Comment: Would just not allowing audits on questions that are currently closed be a good resolution in your mind @SamuelLiew?

Comment: @YaakovEllis yes, mods usually close/delete+undelete to attempt to bump posts out of being an audit. So posts with any past history of being closed or deleted should not be used as audits.

Comment: @SamuelLiew if we block all posts that have been closed from being used in audits, then how do we audit-test if users would recognize a post that should legitimately be closed?

Comment: @YaakovEllis There are multiple types of audits for each queue. We probably need to make a list of them for a clearer understanding of how each type of audit are selected, since we can't just make a blanket change for all of them. Maybe let mods have a "remove as audit" post menu option or something.

Comment: @SamuelLiew we're planning to do a deeper dive on audits in the future (or an audit audit, if you prefer). Just trying to think of quicker fixes we can consider that can help in the meantime, without being disruptive to the good things that currently exist with audits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were hoping to address this issue as part of the last phase of our Review Queues overhaul. However, it quickly became apparent when diving into this request and others related to audits, that improving audits is its own project that's going to require more user research, as well as potential Community Manager/Moderator process changes.

We see the merit in this suggestion and have marked it as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). Improving audits is not on our [Q3 2021 roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368049/) and won't be prioritized in the near future, but we have added it to our backlog.