# Is Stack Overflow in need of more moderation when it comes to new members?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, quality-improvement

I do not want to come across as unwelcoming towards new members that Stack Overflow takes in on a daily basis. But from the recent moderation of questions I've done, I believe there should be some more regulation when it comes to question formulation from new contributors. It really is frustrating to see a wave of "questions" that do not ask anything at all, but only have a line of error and a suggestion asking on "what to do next"? It could be something like automatic moderation wherein a question is not allowed to be posted if it doesn't have these criteria:

- At least one code snippet.
- A floor limit of number of words required to avoid questions that have only titles. I suggest keeping this limit high enough.
- Maybe greying out the "Review your question" button till the OP checks at least some number of related questions that come under the "Similar questions" pane. I think most new members do not even care about scrolling that pane and hence the reason for so many duplicate questions.

Now I'm not a very old member myself and I've recently turned to moderation after reaching the rep that I have (after a long break) and it's not satisfying to see the quality of questions being asked by newer contributors. Also, there have been several feature requests in earlier posts, some almost >5 years old but I believe moderation has remained untouched when it comes to new questions. I think there needs to be done more, add more features during the question formulation phase to at least maintain some quality. There are just so many such questions that moderators new and old spend most of their time moderating on rather actually focusing on high-quality questions that sometimes get ignored and deserve the attention they require.

Stack Exchange in the only *regulated* form of Q&A and that's what actually defines it. As members and moderators, we need to have more automated features for moderation.

Comment: strongly related: [Triage needs to be fixed urgently...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/839601)

Comment: I agree with Samuel's _skipfest_. It just destroys the whole joy of moderating and I fear this will be damaging in the long run since moderators will leave their roles and then this would result in a vicious cycle.

Comment: code Snippet and code in general is never needed to ask a good question.

Comment: Know that this is not a new problem. Moderation is a never-ending muck-raking exercise, but if you are relatively new to the task it can look as if the muck is new too. That we have good and even great content is the result of this endless Sisyphusean task of raking mud, most of which is now gone and so invisible to our newer rake wielders. Don’t despair, just... keep raking!

Comment: What else do you think would help in moderation of first posts? We have [first posts review qeue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) to take care of them for now.  _till the OP checks at least some number of related questions that come under the "Similar questions" pane._ So if users don't check for duplicates, do you think they will 'check' for some number of related questions that are dupes? _A floor limit of # of words required to avoid questions that have only titles._ if I understand this correctly, a word limit on the question body to prevent title only questions?

Comment: @weegee Well we could of course develop the first posts review and moderation further. As moderators we're here to provide inputs and if required work on implementing them. That's our job - in keeping the forum clean. We could add more features that prevent users from not checking similar questions/dupes. For example, you can ask If the user has checked for dupes, if he/she selects 'yes' and if it solves the problem then the question cannot be allowed to be posted. If the user selects 'no'; then again the question cannot be posted. We can certainly keep improving the existing system.

Comment: @Shiv_90 Failing to see how would that improve anything, if users at first place don't check for dupes when they are shown similar questions, do you think they'll be honest in clicking that checkbox?

Comment: Your point is fully valid, there is no doubt about that. The current form of moderation is also well developed; no question about that too. But my concern (which many moderators share) is that at SO there has been an influx of low quality content recently. And that's why most of the popular questions are several years old. I'm no radical innovator myself who asserts that moderation at SO is poor and requires an overhaul; no that's not true. I only hope that such content becomes more regulated over time.

Comment: The question interface ***definitely*** needs improvement (it sets up an expectation of a forum (e.g. fails to mention the time scale Stack Overflow operates at (minutes, not days))), but why would you be concerned about new questions? There are now [19,811,547 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and the 8000 new questions every day amounts to 0.04%. Why not largely ignore them and tend to existing questions instead?

Comment: To start with, it's very difficult to identify new members, as distinct from new accounts:(

Comment: So I see: `First posts Retired
Help new users learn to use the site by reviewing their first posts.

Review tasks
Stats
History
This queue has been retired.
No new items will be added to this queue.

If you’re looking for more to review, return to the Review queues main page.`