# Require the user to enter details when reviewing a question as "Requires Editing"

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

During Triage reviews, when "Requires Editing" is clicked, it should display a popup with a text box, prompting for a brief explanation of why they chose that option. I think this is a good idea for several reasons:

- Help and Improvement reviewers will be able to see this information. This way, if a reviewer notices something subtle (but perhaps still important) the editors are sure to be aware of it, even if it's overshadowed by more obvious issues.
- Users won't need to worry about being review-suspended for choosing this option for a non-obvious reason. For example, what if everyone else thinks it's Unsalvageable for omitting details, when in reality those details are there but just extremely easy to miss due to bad formatting?
- Having an extra prompt will significantly cut back on accidental clicks on "Requires Editing". It's also an excellent place to tell the user that "Requires Editing" is only for posts that can be improved *by the community*.

Comment: I also think Help and Improvement reviewers should be able to push a post back into triage. This way mistakes made clicking "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvageable" won't really matter anymore.

Comment: I think the third point (an extra prompt) is quite important...I've certainly pressed the wrong button (usually Leave Open on a question I meant to close) on a (very small!) number of reviews due to a slip of the mind (of the sort that makes us sometimes crack an egg down the drain and toss the shell into the recipe).  In most cases, I can just go take the opposite action outside of the queue, but feeding it into H&I is more harmful due to wasting others' time too.

Comment: They are probably already planning changes to Triage (and other things) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346901).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Should I link to this in a comment there or something?

Comment: Its a good suggestion, I have only one but... if you're going to be typing to explain how and why it needs editing... you could also be typing to edit it straight away. Still, it's a good ward against misclicks.

Comment: Ostensibly this goes against the purpose of triage, which is to [quickly sort questions into different categories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work/295674#295674). But I'm not sure triage is actually serving its purpose in that regard, so maybe that's not so bad.

Comment: I made the same suggestion and it was extremely well received so hopefully they are considering this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394506/6083675