# Lift of suspended from reviewing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

after noting that I've been suspended from reviews:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again
> on Sep 2 at 14:03. Your review on triage/26550106 wasn't helpful. The
> "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community
> users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable
> question into a better shape. If a question can be closed or can only
> be improved/clarified by the question asker, please use the
> "Unsalvageable" option instead. If in doubt always use the "Skip"
> option. For more information, see Getting banned from Triage reviews
> and How does the Triage queue work?.

I investigated on the topic and noted that I was using the "Requires Editing" button wrong all the time. I already read:

- [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work)
- [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me)
- [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)

on this topic and am now sure I understand the queue and the options correctly. I'm sorry if this caused any trouble for others.

To be honest, the message only showed up to me now (today) and not for the past weeks (the suspension was issued on 30 June). I don't know why as I normally check SO at least every two days. Maybe there was one suspension earlier which was also not visible to me too. If this might be the case I take the suspension. If there were none, is there a way to get the suspension revoked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an appeal process for review queue access suspension?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380508/is-there-an-appeal-process-for-review-queue-access-suspension)

Comment: You may have been suspended before without noticing. The duration of your suspension indicates this. The duration double each time, if I remember correctly.

Comment: The mods make such a long ban so that you're very likely to see it and do research into why you were banned, like you've done. In addition to this meta post, writing a message on the [Bad SO Reviews](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews) chat explaining the you want your ban to be lifted and how you now understand the proper use of Triage options may help.

Comment: You were previously review banned in Apr and May for the same reason. Since you've seen this now I'm going to reset the duration and lift the review suspension.